# Calling function defined in python class. How function are called?

Tags: python

```
class Vector:
    def __init__(self, x=0, y=0):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
    
    def __repr__(self):
        return 'Vector(%r, %r)' % (self.x, self.y)

v=Vector(2, 3)
print(v)
```

In above case: how is repr being called when I print v?

Comment: `__repr__` is a hook used by the `repr` function, which is implicitly called by `print` when you print an objext

Comment: What do you mean *"how"*? That's what's defined by the interpreter; when you `print` something, it needs to get a printable form.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may call this method *explicitly* like this:

```
In [2]: v.__repr__()                                                                                                    
Out[2]: 'Vector(2, 3)' 

In [3]: print(v.__repr__())                                                                                             
Vector(2, 3)

In [4]: type(v.__repr__())                                                                                              
Out[4]: str
```

The main idea behind this - define a method that is called *implicitly* when you call `print(v)`.

There's actually one more function in between (so called build-in function) - `repr` (see [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#repr)). If you don't define `__repr__` it will print some default values.

```
In [1]: class Vector: 
   ...:     def __init__(self, x=0, y=0): 
   ...:         self.x = x 
   ...:         self.y = y 
   ...:                                                                                                                 

In [2]: v = Vector(2, 3)                                                                                                

In [3]: print(v)                                                                                                        
<__main__.Vector object at 0x108e97a60>
```

So you may control what it returns:

> A class can control what this function returns for its instances by defining a `__repr__()` method.

Answer (score 0):

The `__repr__` method is called by the builtin function `repr` and is what is echoed on your python shell when it evaluates an expression that returns an object. When you will just print the `v` variable it will print the `return` of that function. When you will not include the `__repr__` you will get `<__main__.Vector object at 0x037B2CA0>` where `at` is thee place in memory

Answer (score 0):

**repr** is a special built-in function of python. Basically, whenever python finds this method within the context of an object, it'll print what this function returns when you attempt to print the object as its "representation"!

Built-in functions can commonly be identified by the double underscores on each side.

You can find the other built-in functions [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#repr).

Answer (score 0):

This can realize your idea

```py
class Vector:
    def __init__(self, x=0, y=0):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y

    def __str__(self):
        return self.__repr__()

    def __repr__(self):
        return 'Vector(%r, %r)' % (self.x, self.y)

v=Vector(2, 3)
print(v)
```

And you can learn more from this answer: [Difference between __str__ and __repr__?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1436703/difference-between-str-and-repr)